# Divide the value of non-blank cells (in a column) amongst empty cells and repeat with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I start with a sheet like this:

```
colB:
row1: 15
row2: (empty)
row3: (empty)
row4: 60
row5: (empty)
row6: 45
row7: 88
row8: (empty)
row9: 10
...
rowN: 56
```

I want to divide the value of non-empty cells (for example, 15 in row 1) into the number of following cells that are blank. This means that, after transformation, column B would look like this:

```
colB:
row1: 5
row2: 5
row3: 5
row4: 30
row5: 30
row6: 45
row7: 44
row8: 44
row9: 10
...
rowN: 56
```

I don't have any idea how to do that. Anyone can help me, pls?

Comment: Interesting question! How do you know when the data in column B has ended? Is there a marker in column A that will serve as a stopping point?

Comment: Not so hard, but as @DanWagner said, where do you stop?

Comment: I have column A with students name. Column A and column B should have the same number of rows.

Comment: Column B stops where column A stops.

Answer (score 2):

So divide the number by the count of blanks + 1? (15 / 3) unless there are no blanks then divide by 1? (45 == 45)

This will do that up-to the last cell in B by anchoring a filled cell, looking at its vertical offsets then re-anchoring when one is not empty;

```
Dim max As Long, i As Long, cell As Range

Set cell = Range("B1")
max = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Do
    i = i + 1
    If (cell.Offset(i, 0).value <> "") Then
        Range(cell, cell.Offset(i - 1, 0)).value = cell.value / i
        Set cell = cell.Offset(i, 0)
        i = 0
    End If

    If cell.Row = max Then Exit Sub
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but I'm not sure I understand your code. The line: Range(cell, cell.Offset(i - 1, 0)).value = cell.value / i  it's wrong (type mismatch). Can you explain me more, pls? thank you!

Comment: One of the cells must not contain a numeric value

Comment: I have to check if cell.value is valid !?

Comment: So there are letters in B amongst the numbers?

Comment: Above the line that fails add `Debug.Print cell.Value, Len(cell.Value), TypeName(cell.Value)` - run the code, when it throws an error what is the last line in the debug window? (ctrl+G)

Comment: **Effort 13 String** - Effort is the column B name. But the error is the same: cell.value / i

Comment: Well `Effort` is not numeric so cannot be used in a mathematical expression.

Comment: Alex, thank you very much. You are right! The first row was a String. I have to start from the 2nd row. Thanks a lot for your patience!